# Is a proof one kind of computation?

Tags: computer-science, proof-theory

Is proving mathematical theorems one kind of computing? I read somewhere in a book that proofs are one kind of computation. I am not talking about formal proofs, I am talking about the informal natural language arguments that mathematicians use in their daily work.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. If you allow formal proofs, then the answer is a strong "yes" (this is[curry howard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), which is itself 2/3 of the [computational trinity](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/computational+trilogy)). If you're not looking at formal proofs, then I don't know how you could prove a precise statement relating informal proofs with computation. Of course, formal proofs are meant to be a precise version of how mathematicians informally argue, so you can kind of identify the two.